# PySerial API thinks the com port is still open during a write(), why?

Tags: python, serial-port, blocking, pyserial

I am using PySerial (a Python API for serial communication) to send AT commands to a Nokia phone via bluetooth.

```
import serial
com = serial.Serial()
com.port = 19
com.timeout = 0 #also tried a timeout value greater than 0.
try:
    com.open()
    # at this point I turn off the phone.
    com.write("AT\r\n")
    print com.readlines()
except SerialException, e:
    print e
```

Just after I open() the com, I turn off the phone. Then, I write("AT\r\n"). At this point, the function blocks and the runtime hangs.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

With a timeout set to `0`, you desactivate the timeout parameter, the `read()/readlines()` becomes a blocking call. The caller will be blocked until the device answers.
Try to set a non-zero timeout value to your serial connection `com = serial.Serial(timeout=0.5)`.

If it still hangs, the problem should be in the bluetooth stack.

Comment: I just tried with timeout=0.5 but it still hangs. (The phone I use is Nokia E52)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, what you are looking for is the writeTimeout and not the timeout argument. Late answer, I know, but I still needed it and I guess I'm not the only one.